# Users can't load Facebook app

Tags: php, facebook, heroku

I have created a Facebook app with heroku. I've given the canvas url and other data. My problem is an error that users get when they try using it: "page is removed by author". They can't load the corresponding page. But I had no errors and I can preview it correctly.

Comment: I think we need more details about the error before being able to help, but I do hope that other people who have also been through this can help you.

Comment: A screenshot might help :).  Have you checked the Facebook/Heroku help pages?

Comment: or give us your app link

Comment: This is error: Sorry, this page isn't available
The link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed

Comment: This is about as little info as we got before. Are you gonna give us some _real_ information that we can work with now (canvas URL on Facebook, your app’s URLs, …), or can this question be closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your sandbox mode. I think that it will be on.